# Gradle multiproject define dependency on root project

Tags: dependencies, gradle, multi-project

I have a multi project gradle build, configured in this way:

```
root
  |
  |---- projectA
  |
  |---- projectB
```

I want to declare in the `root/build.gradle` a dependency for all nested projects, this is the file:

```
subprojects {
      version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
      repositories {
           mavenLocal()
           mavenCentral()
           maven {
               url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/'
           }
       }
}

allprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2'
    }
}
```

But when I execute the build, I have:

```
* What went wrong:
```

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'code'.

```
No signature of method:
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2]
```

Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`compile` method is part of the plugin you've been using ([reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html)).

```
allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    //so that we can use 'compile', 'testCompile' for dependencies

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically you'll want `subprojects` here, rather than `allprojects`.

Comment: **The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.**

Answer (score 13):

If you got the **'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins** error, try this

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        dependencies {
            implementation "YOUR DEPENDENCIES"
        }
    }
}
```