# How to declare common dependencies in multimodule gradle project on parent folder

Tags: gradle

I've multi-module gradle project. Let's say project `parent` has modules `module1` and `module2`.

I have included both the modules in `settings.gradle` in the parent project as well.

When I declare the common dependencies in `build.gradle` of parent project, both the project is not compiling but when I add the dependencies in `build.gradle` of each module then the modules are compiling successfully.

Any Idea how can I do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare dependencies for all modules in your project using the allprojects statement in your parent module. This is the essential way of doing so in your parent build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    // Plugins can go here, example:
    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies {
        // Dependencies go here, example:
        compile group: 'org.apache.shiro', name: 'shiro-core', version: '1.4.0'
    }
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19857431/9647266) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664571/9647266) answer for more insight on the configuration point of a multi project.
Also have a look at the Gradle [documentation](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) about this topic for a deep dive.

Comment: I would note as well, when working with multi-module projects, that you all the name of that project in the settlings.gradle e.g.

`
rootProject.name = 'TEST_PROJECT'
include 'ModuleOne'
include 'ModuleTwo'
`